# Javafx filechooser without application? (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, filechooser

I tried making a JavaFX file chooser, but soon realized that I had to use an JavaFX Application to do that.

I'm just wondering if there is any way to do this with just a function. 
If there is any other ways to select files using the Windows file chooser in Kotlin, that would be useful too.

Comment: Maybe if you provided some context... is this a Java Swing app? Is it an AWT app? If it is a Swing app: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html

Comment: @PranavA. Im not shure i get what you're saying. Im making a Kotlin program, and i want to create a Javafx filechooser. Not a JFilechooser or a JWSFilechooser. A javafx filechooser

Comment: So this is a non-GUI app?

Comment: @Slaw Yes, so when i think about it, this is kind of a stupid question as i could just use javafx gui instead.

Comment: @Slaw Thought it would be nice to be able to do this without having to learn new javafx stuff